# How to remove margin below alert in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, erb, bootstrap-5

I'm working on Ruby On Rails and in `.html.erb` file i'm using Bootstrap 5.

I have extra padding:

[with extra padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soxpl.png)

And how to do like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2HZh.png)

Code:

```
<div class="alert alert-primary">
  <%= link_to 'Войти в аккаунт', sign_in_path, class: 'sign-up-text' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this about *collapsing margin* ? no way to guess from screenshots, could be anything else. We are missing that part of code demonstrating your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.alert` has a bottom margin, use `.mb-0` to get rid of it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.css">


<div class="alert alert-primary">
  alert alert-primary
</div>
<div class="bg-success">
  other content
</div>

<div class="alert alert-primary mb-0">
  alert alert-primary mb-0
</div>
<div class="bg-success">
  other content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `g-0` class to disable guttter. Read more on the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/)